# Variation on Harmonic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to establish the convergence or divergence of the following variant of the harmonic series:
$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}\cdots$$

Where the sign pattern has period 5, ie, it looks like this: ++---++---++---....

My thought has been to find a regrouping that diverges, since I only need to find one in order to show the series is divergent. I tried to bound this series below by increasing the denominator on the positive terms, and decreasing it on the negative terms to yield a series like $$\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}\right)+ \cdots$$

but I'm pretty sure this will converge. I don't really know what approach to take next. A hint would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the first two is
$\dfrac1{5n+1}+\dfrac1{5n+2}
\lt \dfrac{2}{5n}
$
and the sum of the last 3 is
$\dfrac1{5n+3}+\dfrac1{5n+4}+\dfrac1{5n+5}
\gt \dfrac{3}{5n+5}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{5n+1}+\dfrac1{5n+2}
-(\dfrac1{5n+3}+\dfrac1{5n+4}+\dfrac1{5n+5})
&\lt  \dfrac{2}{5n}-\dfrac{3}{5n+5}\\
&=\dfrac{2 - n}{5 n (n + 1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{5 n (n + 1)}-\dfrac{1}{5  (n + 1)}\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of this diverges
to $-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes short work of the problem, if only I had seen this strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Denote your sequence as $\sum a_k $. Consider the regrouping $\sum b_k$ where
$$ b_k = a_{5k-4} + a_{5k-3} + a_{5k-2} + a_{5k-1} + a_{5k} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{5k-4} + \frac{1}{5k-3} - \frac{1}{5k-2} - \frac{1}{5k-1} -\frac{1}{5k} $$
Combine the terms using the common denominator $(5k-4)(5k-3)(5k-2)(5k-1)(5k)$. This yields a polynomial of degree four divided by a polynomial of degree five. Polynomial long division gives a polynomial of degree zero over a polynomial of degree one. Use the limit comparison test with the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ to conclude that the regrouping $\sum b_k$ is divergent.

Every regrouping of a convergent sequence is itself convergent. Since $\sum b_k$ diverges, we can conclude $\sum a_k$ diverges as well.

Comment: This can be done much more simply. See my answer.